# How to Submit a Comment?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

OK I give up. How do I post a comment on a question or answer without offering a fully-blown response? I can see ways to mark a post as being a favourite, on this site or on facebook or twitter. I can see ways to link to a post, edit it, or flag it as disorderly. Apart from that, it seems, I can only post an answer.

Why do I feel so stupid?

Comment: You need to earn 50 reputation before you can comment on posts that are not your own. See [the privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). (Just to make sure this isn't an actual crazy bug: you should be able to see an "add comment" link here because this is your own question; can you?)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have at least **50** reputation to be able to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).  As of now, you seem to only have 26 reputation on Stack Overflow so you're not able to do so *yet*.

One of the reasons for it is to limit where new users can write things without restriction.  Questions and answers are immediately visible to everyone as they bump the question up on the home page.  It's also possible for others to clean up the post if necessary.  Comments are hard to track unless you specifically watch someone's activity.  Also nobody else but the owner and moderators can edit or delete comments making cleanup more difficult.

Another reason is that it reduces the chances that a spammer could spam comments instead of just questions or answers.  With the above reason explaining why this is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but only on specific places. You have 26 reputation, you need at least 50 reputation to be able to comment everywhere. See [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) page